# Mailchimp different background colors for repeatable

Tags: html, css, background-color, repeat, mailchimp

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up a mailchimp template with a repeatable table which background colors can be changed individually.

Currently I have this

```
....

/*
@tab Main Event
@section Header
@tip Set background and text color for main Event
*/
.heading{
  /*@editable*/background-color:#000000;
  /*@editable*/color:#ffffff;
}

....

<table border="0" class="heading padding-20" mc:repeatable>
  <tr>
    <td align="Left" valign="top" width="70%">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x40" mc:edit="logo">
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="top">
      <a href="*|ARCHIVE|*" class="view-in-browser" mc:editable>view in browser</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As a result I can duplicate the repeatable table in the campaign editor. But when I change the background color in the design panel then the background colors of all the tables change, what is not what I want. I understand that logically changing the background color in the design panel (which is linked to the css for the class .heading) will affect all elements having the class .heading. But I can't find and/or figure out how to solve this problem.

What I want is that I can change the background color of an individual "duplicate" of the table.

e.g.

- Table 1 (duplicate) has background-color blue
- Table 2 (duplicate) has background-color green
- ...

Is this even possible?

Thanks for the patience for reading and helping!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targeting all tables by using

```
.heading {
  background-color:#000000;
}
```

You can use the `nth-child` element to target those specific tables according to the order in which they appear.

```
.heading:nth-child(1) {
    background: orange;
}

.heading:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
}
```

You can [read more about it here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But could you be more specific how to implement this logic as a mailchimp template? The css also has to be already declared?

Comment: I am not super familiar with mailchimp but it looks like they have a thing call [CSS inliner](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/use-inline-css-in-campaigns) that will convert your CSS to inline styles which will allow you to use these types of pseudo classes in my answer.

Comment: This would work if the template would be hard-coded every time.

I am using the template system of mailchimp which allows the user/me to create the newsletter by having the mailchimp campaign interface.

I took another way by predefining 3 different blocks using variants and repeatable. Not the best solution but in my case it is good enough.

Thank you anyway for your help and suggestion!

Comment: This use-case of using `background` instead of `background-color` was useful for writing CSS in MailChimp where there are only a very limited number of CSS properties that are available. Just wanted to let you know since your StackOverflow profile has a `#SOreadytohelp`. Thought i'd let you know that you helped one fellow programmer today! Thanks hehe

Comment: @RickyDam ahh nice! Glad the answer helped you out :)